# validation_split in ImageData Generator returns 0 images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to split my data (images) using `ImageDataGenerator` in Keras by setting `validation_split` to some fraction.

Here is my code:

```py
# Generate batches of tensor image data with real-time data augmentation,  looped over in batches 
train_DataGen_Augmnt =ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, 
    featurewise_center=True,
    validation_split=0.2,
    rotation_range=30,
    horizontal_flip=True,
)

# validation data not augmented!
Validation_DataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Flow training images in batches of 32 using train_datagen generator
train_generator = train_DataGen_Augmnt.flow_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    subset='training',   
    target_size=(150, 150),  
    batch_size=32,
    #save_to_dir='images/Agumented'
)

# Flow validation images in batches of 32 using test_datagen generator
validation_generator = Validation_DataGen.flow_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    subset='validation',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
)
```

The splitting seems to work as the data is split but only shows the splitting for training only.

Here is the output when running this:

```
Found 89 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 3 classes.
```

Comment: Do not define a new generator for the validation. Use the same generator you have already defined, i.e. `train_DataGen_Augmnt`.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I tried using the same ImageGenerator for training and validation, yet it says the same. 0 images found belonging to n classes.

Answer (score 1):

use the same generator used for training data generation `train_DataGen_Augmnt` for validation data generation

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to put the validation_split = 0.2 too in your validation_data_gen
it works